# Plugin php code change not being reflected

Tags: magento2

I have written a simple module/plugin which logs "Hello World" to the debug log.

- Step 0: Switch to developer mode
- Step 1: Plugin logs "Hello World" to    the debug file
- Step 2: Change the code to log "Hello universe" instead
- Step 3: Delete `generated/code/*` and `generated/metadata/*`
- Step 4: Clean cache
- **Step 5 (Error):** Plugin logs "Hello World" to the debug    file instead of "Hello Universe"

I have also tried running `setup:di:compile`, enabling/disabling/upgrading the module.

*Additional Information*

- Magento 2 deployment is on AWS using LightSail.
- The plugin is an "after" plugin which extends the `GetAvailableMethods` function to get all available payment methods

Answer (score 2):

Flush Magento 2 cache

Go to Magento root directory & execute below command

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: If still you face issue, search for "Hello World" string in directory.
If found replace it.